# Estrutura de repetição while não repete trecho específico do código!

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um jogo simples de par ou ímpar em python que não executa de forma correta!

Quando o jogador vence, o jogo não pergunta novamente se ele que par ou ímpar! Como posso resolver?

```
from random import randint
P_OU_I = ' '
v = 0
while True:
    player = int(input('Digite um valor: '))
    computador = randint(0, 10)
    total = player + computador
    while P_OU_I not in 'PI':
        P_OU_I = str(input('Par ou ímpar: [P/I] ')).strip().upper()[0]
    print(f'Você jogou {player} e o computador {computador}. Total de {total}')
    if P_OU_I == 'P':
        if total % 2 == 0:
            print('Você VENCEU!')
            v = v + 1
        else:
            print('Você PERDEU!')
            break
    elif P_OU_I == 'I':
        if total % 2 == 1:
            print('Você VENCEU!')
            v = v + 1
        else:
            print('Você PERDEU!')
            break
    print('Vamos jogar novamente...')
print(f'GAME OVER! Você venceu {v}')
```

Comment: Quais foram suas tentativas? sugiro [**editar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/522046/edit) sua perguna e acrescentar esses detalhes. Ah! antes de mais nada dá uma olhadinha, em como criar um [mre] assim poderá elaborar uma boa pergunta e as chances dela ser fechada (ou seja, não ter chances de receber respostas) reduz muito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade seu código está executando corretamente de acordo com o que foi programado, ele só não está fazendo o que você deseja porque você não programou como deveria.

O seu erro é o seguinte: Na linha 8 você faz uma conferência para saber se já foi escolhido par ou ímpar

```
while P_OU_I not in 'PI':
```

Na primeira execução o código entra neste `while` pois a variável ainda se encontra vazia. No entanto, note que você não limpou essa variável em nenhum momento após a primeira rodada.

Para corrigir é bem simples, você só precisa definir novamente `P_OU_I = ' '` tal qual fez no início do código. Veja como fica após corrigido:

```
from random import randint
P_OU_I = ' '
v = 0

while True:
    player = int(input('Digite um valor: '))
    computador = randint(0, 10)
    total = player + computador
    while P_OU_I not in 'PI':
        P_OU_I = str(input('Par ou ímpar: [P/I] ')).strip().upper()[0]
    print(f'Você jogou {player} e o computador {computador}. Total de {total}')
    if P_OU_I == 'P':
        if total % 2 == 0:
            print('Você VENCEU!')
            v += 1
        else:
            print('Você PERDEU!')
            break
    elif P_OU_I == 'I':
        if total % 2 == 1:
            print('Você VENCEU!')
            v += 1
        else:
            print('Você PERDEU!')
            break
    P_OU_I = ' '
    print('Vamos jogar novamente...')
print(f'GAME OVER! Você venceu {v}')
```

Também mudei algumas coisas que acho que ficam melhores. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Isso resolveu meu problema! Obrigado!